# Meaning of sp_who Status in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can someone tell me what the statuses mean in SQL Server's sp_who command?  Why might a spid be suspended?  What does it mean to be "runnable"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 30):

Pretty easy to find answer online. [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-who-transact-sql)

**dormant.** SQL Server is resetting the session.

**running.** The session is running one or more batches. When Multiple Active Result Sets (MARS) is enabled, a session can run multiple batches. For more information, see Using Multiple Active Result Sets (MARS).

**background.** The session is running a background task, such as deadlock detection.

**rollback.** The session has a transaction rollback in process.

**pending.** The session is waiting for a worker thread to become available.

**runnable.** The session's task is in the runnable queue of a scheduler while waiting to get a time quantum.

**spinloop.** The session's task is waiting for a spinlock to become free.

**suspended.** The session is waiting for an event, such as I/O, to complete.

Comment: Thanks!  I couldn't find that, but I'm glad you did!

Comment: different users get different hits when searching the same string; Google taylors search results to previous searches done .

Comment: I can't understand the difference between runnable and pending. When a Task is in runnable queue it means it is waiting for a worker thread. Because a task can be proceeded only with a worker. What I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that part of the confusion on this is that there are statuses outside of the list shown above that are seen. Three that come to mind are

- Sleeping
- Awaiting Command
- Other